# Altium layer stack manager problem (change thickness, save it but after I close and open Altium again it doesn't change)

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

I want to explain the problem directly.

I have a two layer PCB. I want to change the dielectric layer thickness to make my PCB's thickness 1.5mm.

> Access to "C:\Program Files\Altium\AD22\filename.PcbDoc.pcbstackup" path is denied

When I made the change in the first step. I was getting an error. Since I realized that this error was caused by windows, I moved the project folder in Altium content to a folder on the desktop. As a result, I was no longer getting the same error when I changed the thickness via the stack manager. But this time, after changing the thickness, saving and exiting Altium and then opening Altium back and checking the thickness, I saw that it remained at the old default value.

Comment: This seems to be a simple software issue and doesn't seem to be relevant for EESE. You better ask this type of question in the official Altium forum.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic. (It is about a software problem, not electronics engineering; despite the software being _for_ electronics engineering).